# Select filtered values and apply the selection on a different filter in a second workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want select some filtered cells in a sheet and apply the selection on a filter in a second workbook.

I tried it with a modified code found here.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Arr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WB_Macro.Sheets("Current Stage").Selection.Value)
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Arr(i) = CStr(Arr(i))
    Next i
    Selection.AutoFilter
    WB_New.Sheets("Consolidated EOY ´20-CO20-21").Range("$A$2:$C$1048576").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: What happens when you run that?  You can't use `Selection.Value` if the selection isn't a single area (eg. in a filtered table with hidden rows the selection is likely not a single area)

Comment: I get the error message "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: There is no line only this message the debugger is not showing

Comment: Is the VB Project locked?

Comment: No it isn't locked

Comment: Then maybe step through your code using F8 and see where the error is.